# How to render normals to surface of object in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, quaternions, normalize

I found [the example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=norm#webgl_geometry_normals) in threejs.org, that draws arrows normals, it is what I need. But arrows is complexed object and created by ArrowHelper. 
I looked in source code and found setDirection method.

```
function setDirection( dir ) {

    // dir is assumed to be normalized

    if ( dir.y > 0.99999 ) {

        this.quaternion.set( 0, 0, 0, 1 );

    } else if ( dir.y < - 0.99999 ) {

        this.quaternion.set( 1, 0, 0, 0 );

    } else {

        axis.set( dir.z, 0, - dir.x ).normalize();

        radians = Math.acos( dir.y );

        this.quaternion.setFromAxisAngle( axis, radians );

    }

};
```

I tried to immpliment algorithm for setting rotation for Vector3 with using quaternion, but I still have norlams that looks at `{x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}`.

And my question is:
How to calculate an vector in order to draw a normal line from surface into space, in order to get the same picuter: [image]

**UPD**:
I use CylinderGeometry.

**UPD2**:
I've resolved it. [Look at my codepen](http://codepen.io/artzub/pen/zZXjdM)

Comment: You need to calculate the normal of what? Do you have a `bufferGeometry` or a `geometry`? Or you have three `vector` which are the normals of the vertices of a face? This question is totally incomplete.

Comment: I have the same geometry that into threejs example. ``CylinderGeometry``

Comment: I suggest going through your geometry faces and manually computing normal for each triangle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to view the vertex normals of your mesh. You can use `VertexNormalsHelper` like so:

```
var vnh = new THREE.VertexNormalsHelper( mesh, 1, 0xff0000 );
scene.add( vnh );
```

[VertexNormalsHelper](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/helpers/VertexNormalsHelper)

three.js r.84

Comment: The greatest thanks for your help! I've done it =) http://codepen.io/artzub/pen/zZXjdM